# jQuery 0 instead of Nan

Tags: javascript, jquery, radio-button, nan

I've created a questionaire with jQuery.
There are 5 Radio Buttons each question.
value = 0, value = 1, value = 2, value = 3, value = 4

If someome answerd nothing, I want to set the value 0.
Now will "NaN" pushed into my array. I can't find a soultion.

```
<div class="tab-pane active" role="tabpanel" id="step1">                                
<div class="qhead">
    <h3>Leadership</h3>
    <span class="underline-small"></span>
</div>
<div class="questions">                             
    <!-- Fragen -->
    <div class="row">
        <h4>Das ist Frage 1</h4>                                    
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <p>Das ist Frage 1</p>
        <label class="radio radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="q1" id="q1" value="0"><i class="input-helper"></i>Nicht aktiv</label>
        <label class="radio radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="q1" id="q1" value="1"><i class="input-helper"></i>Schon davon gehört</label>
        <label class="radio radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="q1" id="q1" value="2"><i class="input-helper"></i>Manche arbeiten damit</label>
        <label class="radio radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="q1" id="q1" value="3"><i class="input-helper"></i>Wird sind sehr gut</label>
        <label class="radio radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="q1" id="q1" value="4"><i class="input-helper"></i>Wir setzen Maßstäbe</label>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <p>Das ist Frage 2</p>
        <label class="radio radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="q2" id="q2" value="0"><i class="input-helper"></i>Nicht aktiv</label>
        <label class="radio radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="q2" id="q2" value="1"><i class="input-helper"></i>Schon davon gehört</label>
        <label class="radio radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="q2" id="q2" value="2"><i class="input-helper"></i>Manche arbeiten damit</label>
        <label class="radio radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="q2" id="q2" value="3"><i class="input-helper"></i>Wird sind sehr gut</label>
        <label class="radio radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="q2" id="q2" value="4"><i class="input-helper"></i>Wir setzen Maßstäbe</label>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <p>Das ist Frage 3</p>
        <label class="radio radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="q3" id="q3" value="0"><i class="input-helper"></i>Nicht aktiv</label>
        <label class="radio radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="q3" id="q3" value="1"><i class="input-helper"></i>Schon davon gehört</label>
        <label class="radio radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="q3" id="q3" value="2"><i class="input-helper"></i>Manche arbeiten damit</label>
        <label class="radio radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="q3" id="q3" value="3"><i class="input-helper"></i>Wird sind sehr gut</label>
        <label class="radio radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="q3" id="q3" value="4"><i class="input-helper"></i>Wir setzen Maßstäbe</label>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <p>Das ist Frage 1</p>
        <label class="radio radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="q4" value="0"><i class="input-helper"></i>Nicht aktiv</label>
        <label class="radio radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="q4" value="1"><i class="input-helper"></i>Schon davon gehört</label>
        <label class="radio radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="q4" value="2"><i class="input-helper"></i>Manche arbeiten damit</label>
        <label class="radio radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="q4" value="3"><i class="input-helper"></i>Wird sind sehr gut</label>
        <label class="radio radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="q4" value="4"><i class="input-helper"></i>Wir setzen Maßstäbe</label>
    </div>
    <!-- Fragen Ende -->
</div>
<ul class="list-inline pull-right padtop">
    <li><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary next-step">Speichern und weiter</button></li>
</ul>
```

```
$(".done").click(function (e) {
//Count Questions
var step1  = $("#step1 p").length;
var step1a = 1;                 
var step1e = step1a + step1;

var questionnaire1 = []
for (var i=step1a; i<step1e; ++i ){
  var finalVar = "input[name='q"+i+"']:checked";
  var varCont = parseInt($(finalVar).val());
  questionnaire1.push(varCont);     
}
});
```

Example: The result is [1,4,NaN,3,0]
For correct data I need [1,4,0,3,0]

I've tried it with a if statement, but this also does not work.

```
$(".done").click(function (e) {
//Count Questions
var step1  = $("#step1 p").length;
var step1a = 1;                 
var step1e = step1a + step1;

var questionnaire1 = []
for (var i=step1a; i<step1e; ++i ){
var finalVar = "input[name='q"+i+"']:checked";
if($(finalVar).val() == "NaN") 
{questionnaire1.push(0)}
else{questionnaire1.push($(finalVar).val());}   
}
});
```

Comment: What's wrong with a mere `if` in between?

Comment: Post a complete code example please.

Comment: @Sirko I've tried, but it does not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You second try almost got it. You just missed the fact, that `.val()` returns `null`, if no option is selected and not `"NaN"`. The `NaN` was just the result of your failed call to `parseInt()`.

To adapt change to this:

```
  var val = $(finalVar).val();
  if ( val == null) {
    questionnaire1.push(0)
  } else {
    questionnaire1.push( parseInt( val, 10 ) );
  }
```

[Example Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9mvL1f45/)

Answer (score 0):

You should loop through each row (question) and get the checked radio button from that and use the value. If nothing is checked, use 0.

```
$(".done").click(function (e) {

   var questionnaire1 = [];

   $.each($(".row"),function(x,y){

      var c= $(y).find("input[type]:checked");

      var v=0;
      if(c.length)
      {
        v=parseInt(c.val());
      }
      questionnaire1.push(v);

   });
  console.log(questionnaire1);
});
```

[Here](http://jsbin.com/tucisuyexo/edit?html,js,console,output) is  working sample

Comment: From OPs code I get, that the radio buttons are grouped. Your code ignores that grouping currently, but inserts one value for each single radio button.

Comment: This looks like a great solution, but it does not work with my HTML Code (added)

Comment: Take a look at the updated answer. I updated based on your markup.